# Office Add-in - This app isn't supported by the version of exchange server that your account connects to

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins

1. I have Exchange on-premises server with version 2013
2. I wrote an Office add-on which I can install in Office365 account with manifest file with out any issues
3. But, when I try to install the same add-on from my Exchange 2013 OWA > Settings > Manage Add-ins/Apps it says

> This app isn't supported by the version of exchange server that your
>   account connects to

Searching for this issue showing that the issue might be with the requirement set we use in the manifest. But, I used the same requirement set 1.1 which should support Exchange 2013 as mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/office/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets?view=office-js).

**What else should be done to enable Office add-on in my Exchange 2013?**

Any advice/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you link to a copy of the manifest reproduces the error? Checking the requirement set was a good place to start. There should be something in the manifest that's causing this error. The other thing to check is that Exchange 2013 is updated to the latest CU. Support for requirement set 1.1 was added in Exchange 2013 SP1.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. Here is the [link](https://vaddins.vtiger.com/office/manifest.xml) to manifest. Please check and let me know if there is any issue in this.

Comment: Could you share what your exchange 2013 build number is?

Comment: It's 1395.4 [ref](http://sc.vtiger.net/screenshots/Screenshot-at-20-09-18-17-02-15.png)

Comment: After updating Exchange to latest CU, add-in installation is successful. 

But, I am expecting this add-in to be shown as side bar, same like in Office365 account. I am not sure why it's shown like [this](http://sc.vtiger.net/screenshots/Screenshot-at-21-09-18-14-27-54.png)

Answer (score 0):

@user3752326, I'm glad updating to the latest Exchange 2013 CU solved your installation problem.

The reason why your add-in is not showing up in the side bar is because Exchange 2013 does not support [Add-In Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook). Only Exchange 2016 or Office365 support [Add-In Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook). Exchange 2013 supports legacy add-ins, which show up in the body of the message, as you have it in your [screenshot](http://sc.vtiger.net/screenshots/Screenshot-at-21-09-18-14-27-54.png).